# Given a position $(x,y,z)$ and a direction vector $(x,y,z)$ how to get the new position?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm coding a turtle3D library. Problem is, given a initial position $(x,y,z)$ and a vector for the movement, I do not know how to calculate the new position. Would it just be the sum of the position + vector movement?

Comment: Yes, the new position is the old position plus the displacement.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked